# Area of the region bounded by the line $y=−x$ and the parabola $r= \frac{1}{1+\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, parametric

> Express the area of the region bounded by the line  $y=−x$  and the parabola  $r= \frac{1}{1+\cos(\theta)}$  as an integral in polar coordinates. (Choose limits of integration in the range  $(−\pi,\pi)$ . The integral must evaluate to be positive. Leave expression in the integral form.)

I know that I have to subtract the function on top with the function of the bottom, however I think both equations must both be either in polar coordinates or cartesian coordinates. Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: Your parabola has equation $x=\frac{1}{2}(1-y^2)$. ;-)

Comment: @Pacciu Would you mind explaining why is this?

Comment: Diego, it is really simple algebra. Try to compute $1-y^2$ with $y=r \sin \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{1 + \cos \theta}$ (by polar coordinates): you will find it equals $2x$ with $x=r \cos \theta = \frac{\cos \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$ (again by polar coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In polar coordinates, the line $ y=-x$ becomes $\tan\theta =-1$, which defines the angular limits $[-\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4]$ for the enclosed area. Then, the area is integrated as

$$A=\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4 }\frac12r^2(\theta)d\theta
= \frac12\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac{3\pi}4 }\frac1{(1+\cos\theta)^2}d\theta =\frac{4\sqrt2}3
$$

Comment: Which tool did you used for graphing?

Comment: @Diego - Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your statement that we should "subtract the function on top with the function of the bottom" is incorrect in the context of polar integration. Since we take $r$ as a function of $\theta$ in this context, we subtract the (differential area bounded by the) function with the larger $r$ with the (differential area bounded by the) function with a smaller $r$, which is to say we integrate the "outside function" minus the "inside function".

For this problem, however, there is only one function that gives us the $r$-limits of the region; the curve $y = -x$ only serves to give us the maximal and minimal values of $\theta$.  So, we will end up with an integrand that only involves the function $r(\theta) = \frac 1{1 + \cos \theta}$.

It is important to note that the region lies to the right side of the line $y = -x$.